# Check for particular permission is assigned to user

Tags: security, permissions, permission-sets, platform-encryption

I know userId for an user, but unable to perform check for permission of  **View Encrypted Data**.

Multiple permission Sets are assigned to user.
How to check for a particular permission??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run following query to check permission

> SELECT Id,Name,PermissionsViewEncryptedData FROM Profile